# Iterate Nested list in java

Tags: java, collections, for-loop, tree

I want to display a tree view in my page. For that i will have a List object. List object will contain some more list objects. I don't know how many nested levels i will get. So please tell me, how to navigate through the list.

Sample data i want to display is

- Education

  - Mathematics

    - Trigonometry
  - Science

    - Physics

      - nuclear physics
    - chemistry
  - Social
- Sports

  - cricket
  - foot ball
- Technology

  - mobiles
  - computers

    - laptops
    - pc

Comment: Where does the treeview come from? isit in xml from example?

Comment: I need to get that form Database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a recursive method as shown below :

```
void printList(Collection myList) {
   for(Object o : myList) {
      if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
          printList((Collection)o);
      }
      else {
          print o;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a recursive function :

```
   void display(Object item) {
       print(item);
       if (item instanceof List) 
           for (Object itemInList: (List) list) {
               display(itemInList);
           }
       }
   }
```

If necessary, you can use a level, for indentation for example :

```
   void printItem(Object item, int level) {
       for (int i=0; i<level; i++) System.out.print(" ");
       System.out.println(item);
   }

   void display(List list, int level) {
       printItem(list, level);
       if (item instanceof List) 
           for (Object itemInList: (List) list) {
               display(itemInList, level+1);
           }
       }
   }

   display(topLevelList, 0);
```

Comment: You need to printf the list itself (parent node)